# How can I reconnect with my raspberry pi zero W that has a headless setup?

Tags: wifi, headless, setup

I have a headless setup for the raspberry pi zero W. The first time it worked perfectly. But, when I try to re-connect, using both putty and mobaxterm, I cannot connect it tells me Network error: connection timed out.

The second time, I tried for multiple hours and I honestly believe that I could reconnect out of pure luck. I didn't have to re-download the image or anything.

Today, I have been trying to connect again many times, with no luck at all. I believe the problem is that every time a connect the sim card I find that the wpa_supplicant.conf and the ssh file are gone, for some reason. But, when I see the devices connected to the wifi, I can see the raspberry, so it is all very confusing.

I have looked everywhere in the internet, but all the explanations are about downloading the image and having the initial setup, not about re-connection.

If anyone knows how to solve this, please write a comment.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the command you issue and the full response.

Comment: Plug a monitor in to the device and see if there are any logs on the console?

Comment: *"I find that the wpa_supplicant.conf and the ssh file are gone"* -> That's the way it's supposed to be.  On first boot they are moved from there to the OS root filesystem, which is a second partition you will not be able to see on a Windows computer.  Doing this over and over again will probably cause more problems than it solves, if it does anything at all.

Comment: *"Network error: connection timed out."* ->  This implies there is a record of the address active on the network in play, most likely on the Windows box you are using; the "inactive" status you get from Advanced IP scanner probably confirms this: https://superuser.com/q/1617852/257378 This means there is actually nothing currently using the address, including the Pi.   You should try scanning the whole LAN for an open port 22 (SSH).  There may be other devices in your place with that open, but the MAC address for the Pi should cause it to be listed by name (as in "Rasberry Pi").